# Calculating the offset factor from the eight character key?

Tags: python-3.x, encryption

I'm trying to calculate the offset factor based on the eight character key, which is a string. I have been trying this method:

`EightCharakey = input("Please enter the eight charatcer key used to encrypt the message")
for i in EightCharaKey:
    print (int(ord(i))
    offset = offset + i`
 This outputs (for the last line) `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'` But i know what is wrong however I don't know how to fix it?

Comment: I'm presuming (you don't show where you set it) that `offset` is an integer (`'int'`). `i` is a string you get from looping letter-by-letter of `EightCharaKey`. You cannot add together an integer and a string.

Comment: Did you bother to look up the error message?

Comment: How do i fix then because I have no idea??

Comment: And Yes i have bothered to look up the error message but that still didn't help